# Appending to a DataFrame converts dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending to a pandas.DataFrame, and the dtype of a column is converted in an unexpected way:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':1.0, 'b':'x'}, index=[0])
print df.dtypes
df = df.append({'a':3.0}, ignore_index=True)
print df.dtypes
df = df.append({'a':3.0, 'b':'x'}, ignore_index=True)
print df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
a    float64
b     object
dtype: object
a    float64
b     object
dtype: object
a    object         <- ???
b    object
dtype: object
```

whereas I would have expected a `float64` instead of that `object`.
How can I avoid that conversion?

I am using pandas 0.11.

Comment: Hmm.. strange if I do this I get `float`: `for x in df['a']:
    print(type(x))` outputs: `<class 'float'> for every item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, convert the dict object to DataFrame first:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':1.0, 'b':'x'}, index=[0])
print df.dtypes
df = df.append({'a':3.0}, ignore_index=True)
print df.dtypes
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([{'a':3.0, 'b':'x'}]), ignore_index=True)
print df.dtypes
```

or, a list of dict:

```
df = df.append([{'a':3.0, 'b':'x'}], ignore_index=True)
```

If it's a dict, it will be convert to a Series first, a series contain 3.0 and 'x' must with object dtype.

If it's a list of dict, it will be convert to a DataFrame, DataFrame can have different dtype for every column.

Comment: This reports the `dtypes` as `float64` as expected, any idea why `append`  with a dict is not working as expected?

Comment: This is fixed in master/0.13.1 (when creating the frame to append it was not converting the object dtypes, which is what a dict starts out as). see here:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5995/files#diff-1e79abbbdd150d4771b91ea60a4e1cc7R3628

Comment: Looks like [`DataFrame.append` is deprecated now](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) so `pd.concat` should be used.