# Data type is changed when a dictionary contains int element added by using pd.DataFrame.append()

Tags: python, pandas

When a dictionary is added to an empty DataFrame using the append function of pandas, the elements of type int are converted and stored in the DataFrame.

As shown in the code below, it looks like the conversion to any data type depends on the other elements in the dictionary.

How can we store int types as int types without this behavior? Do I have to convert the data type of the DataFrame afterwards?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["int","float"])
print(df.append({"int":1, "float":0.5},ignore_index=True).dtypes)
"""
int      float64
float    float64
dtype: object
"""

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["str","int","float"])
print(df.append({"str":"test", "int":1, "float":0.5},ignore_index=True).dtypes)
"""
str       object
int       object
float    float64
dtype: object
"""
```

Comment: It should answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281463/appending-to-a-dataframe-converts-dtypes

Comment: With the solution of the above link, `int` are still `object` even put under a list or `pd.DataFrame()`.   Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `infer_objects` to correct dtypes at the end of appending everything to the dataframe.

Also, you can use concat instead of append which has more functionality

```py
In [47]: df.append({"str":"test", "int":1, "float":0.5},ignore_index=True).infer_objects().dtypes                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[47]: 
str       object
int        int64
float    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: `infer_objects` still doesn't work for the first case.  `int` is `float64` in that case.

Comment: But that should not be an issue, i think it only tries to change it if data does not conform to data type assigned.

Comment: The issue is: this doesn't help solving the problem for the first part.