# Why do I get NaT values rather than NaN when adding partial rows to this Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that reads a .csv file into a dataframe and then allows to user to extend the dataframe by adding extra data to it. It will take the last value in the `date` column and start prompting the user for a value day-by-day.

If the user doesn't specify anything for `input` then the value gets cast to a `math.nan`. Except when I go append the row to the dataframe, the supposed `NaN` gets cast to a `NaT`.

I've recreated a reproducible example below.

How do I ensure that my `NaN`s aren't cast to `NaT`s?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03']),
    'weight': [250., 249, 247],
})

last_recorded_date = df['date'].iloc[-1]
next_date = last_recorded_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [next_date, math.nan]

print(df)
#         date weight
# 0 2022-05-01  250.0
# 1 2022-05-02  249.0
# 2 2022-05-03  247.0
# 3 2022-05-06    NaT
```

Comment: Weird indeed. Would you consider using pd.NA instead of math.nan?

Comment: @Drakax very interesting, switching over to use `pd.NA` instead of `math.nan` makes it work the way I want.

Comment: I tried to make the [mre] more minimal - this still appears to exhibit the problem, as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a row from a `list`, the list is first converted to a `Series`. Elements of a `Series` have to be all the same type; the first value is a `datetime`; so every value is converted to a `datetime` in the resulting `Series`. In particular, `math.nan` becomes `NaT`. Pandas **does not** use the existing column types to inform the process; instead, the column types are adjusted as needed - the `weight` column's type expands from `float` to `object`.

From my testing, using a tuple instead seems to fix the problem:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = (next_date, math.nan)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still converts `math.nan` to `NaT`. (I'm using Pandas version 1.4.2).

Comment: Doing further testing, if you take my original reprex and add two "blank" rows in succession. The first one will be `NaT` and the second will be `NaN`... This behavior is weird.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not actually any kind of expert in Pandas; I only understand generally how to use it. Hopefully someone will come along eventually and refine this.

Answer (score 1):

That is weird. But some experimentation reveals some clues:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03']),
    'weight': [250., 249, 247],
    })

# Try this
df.loc[4] = None
```

Raises:

```
FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
```

That doesn't exactly explain why it added `NaT` to the second column but it does indicate that the types need to be specified when appending to the existing dataframe.

One solution, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281944/1609514), is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03']),
    'weight': [250., 249, 247],
    })

next_date = pd.Timestamp('2022-05-04')
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([{'date': next_date, 'weight': np.nan}]), ignore_index=True)
assert (df.dtypes.values == ('<M8[ns]', 'float64')).all()
```

However, this raises:

```
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([{'date': next_date, 'weight': np.nan}]), ignore_index=True)
```

So I guess the right solution is now:

```python
new_row = pd.DataFrame([{'date': next_date, 'weight': np.nan}])
df = pd.concat([df, new_row]).reset_index(drop=True)
assert (df.dtypes.values == ('<M8[ns]', 'float64')).all()
```

But I must ask, why are you appending to a dataframe in this way? It is quite inefficient and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I record my weight every morning on a notepad. After a few weeks, I take the notepad and typically input the data into a CSV. With this script, I would like to insert the new data via cli. So that's why I've programmed it to add one day at a time. Also I wouldn't want the `date` value to be `NaT` just the `weight` value to be `NaN`.

Comment: Ah right. So the inefficiency is not going to be an issue if you are waiting for user input and it is only one row a day. One alternative if you are interested would be to append the new data directly to the csv file. Then, only when you need it, load the entire csv file into a dataframe.

Comment: I replaced the NaT values and made another edit to the answer.  Previously it was not adding the correct index value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03']),
    'weight': [250., 249, 247],
    })

last_recorded_date = df['date'].iloc[-1]

while True:
    next_date = last_recorded_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    weight = input(f"{next_date}: ")
    if weight == 'q':
        break
    elif weight == '':
        weight = math.nan
    else:
        weight = float(weight)

    df.loc[len(df.index)] = [next_date, weight]
    last_recorded_date = next_date

df = df['weight'].replace(pd.NaT, math.nan)

print(df)
```